Cropping a global shapefile just to Europe on R
I am using a shapefile to map ice extent, but I only want it focused on Europe. This is the entire shapefile plotted:

I've tried using a bounding box and clipping the shapefile, but neither of these work. I get an error that "geos_op2_geom("intersection", x, y, ...):

st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE".

ice_extent <- st_read(shapefile_path)

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")

europe_bbox <- st_bbox(c(xmin = -30, xmax = 70, ymin = 30, ymax = 90))
europe_and_surrounding <- st_crop(world, europe_bbox)

ice_extent_europe <- st_intersection(ice_extent, europe_and_surrounding)


st_crs(x) == st_crs(y) is not TRUE". is the clue. To calculate intersection, both datasets needs to have the same CRS. Either convert the CRS of ice_extend to the same CRS as europe_and_surrounding, either opposite way.

As @GrzegorzSapijaszko noted, both datasets need to have the same CRS in order for st_intersection() to work. So does st_crop(), but for some reason it is agnostic towards sf objects with a CRS == NA (at least in the case of the europe_bbox object you created). To project data using the sf package, the function to use is st_transform().
Whether you assign ice_extent the same CRS as europe_and_surrounding or vice versa depends on your use case. This repex assumes two things:

your use case is to create a map for display purposes
your ice_extent data are in a polar coordinate system

If your analysis is for anything other than display only, you will need to ensure the CRS that you choose is appropriate for your use case.
As you did not provide a copy of your ice_extent object, I have used a representative dataset available from this link. That data comes with WGS84/EPSG:4326 as its CRS, I have assigned it NSIDC Sea Ice Polar Stereographic North/EPSG:3411 to replicate the correct workflow. Your actual data may have a different CRS, but the workflow is the same regardless.
One final point. Even though st_crop() can work as in the case of the europe_bbox object you created, it is good practice to always assign a CRS (as shown in the below example).
library(sf)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(ggplot2)

# Load ice extent data previously downloaded to working directory from
# https://usicecenter.gov/Products/ArcticData
# Project to CRS that resembles your plot example for illustrative purposes
ice_extent <- st_read("nic_autoc2024167n_pl_a.shp") %>%
  st_transform(3411)

# Return CRS
st_crs(ice_extent)$input
# [1] "EPSG:3411"

# Load ne_countries() sf
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium")

# Return CRS
st_crs(world)$input
# [1] "WGS 84"

# Create crop bbox and assign CRS using world sf
europe_bbox <- st_bbox(c(xmin = -30, xmax = 70, ymin = 30, ymax = 90),
                       crs = st_crs(world))
  
# Check europe_bbox CRS
st_crs(europe_bbox)$input
# [1] "WGS 84"

# Crop world (will return a warning which you can safely ignore)
europe_and_surrounding <- st_crop(world, europe_bbox)

# Warning message:
# attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all geometries

# Project europe_and_surrounding to same CRS as ice_extent
europe_and_surrounding <- st_transform(europe_and_surrounding, st_crs(ice_extent))

# Return intersection features
ice_extent_europe <- st_intersection(ice_extent, europe_and_surrounding)

# Warning message:
# attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all geometries 

# Plot
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = europe_and_surrounding, colour = "grey75") +
  geom_sf(data = ice_extent_europe, colour = "#e22f33", aes(fill = ICECODE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = "#e22f33",
                    name = "Europe\nIce Extent",
                    labels = "")


